# Share Contact Via Twillion to iPhone

Tags: php, ios, iphone, twilio, contacts

I am looking to create a script to send a contact from [Twillio](https://www.twilio.com/en-us) to my iPhone. The purpose is the contact I send from [Twillio](https://www.twilio.com/en-us) to phone should look exactly the way contact shared by iPhone. Can someone help me,

PS: Is it doable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This kind of depends. Contacts are sent as MMS messages (as it's a file of information). Twilio supports [sending MMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-send-sms-messages-in-php#send-a-message-with-media-mms-in-php) in the US and Canada, so you can do this if that is where you are sending your messages. If you are sending elsewhere in the world, then I'm afraid you can't do so with Twilio and make it look the same as a shared contact.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi philnash, Thanks for feedback, Yes I am trying to send SMS in US. Can you please guide a bit more on how to send MMS and What are the charges etc.

Comment: You can see a guide for how to send SMS and then MMS messages right here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-send-sms-messages-in-php#send-a-message-with-media-mms-in-php. And you can see the pricing here: https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing